# Need to create Swipe Password Screen for my custom application in Android

Tags: android

I am working on an application which needs a swipe password activity for security reasons.
Am not able to find samples anywhere. I just need to show a password screen (3 x 3 grid) just like default swipe password screen in android. Then the user will have 3 chances to swipe and result will be handled accordingly. Any sample provided would be great help.

Answer (score 0):

maybe [**this library ("Android Lock Pattern")**](http://www.androidviews.net/2012/11/android-lock-pattern/) could be handy?

there is also [**this one ("GlowPadView Lockring") **](http://www.androidviews.net/2012/11/glowpadview-lockring/), which is without a pattern password .